# Android 12 Incorrect behavior of script from example for listing folder content

Tags: java, android

I use example for listing folder content from there (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9Tx4JzQFIk).For Android 12 I obtain Android Studio message: "Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk of at least 33, for example 34." When I implement message and I use Android 14, I obtain only subdirectories list (without files) from selected folder .

How do I have to modify it for Android 12? Can you explain me problem? Thank you.

Comment: Post your code.